# Long life storage devices

Tags: hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, storage

Which is the best storage device for long life(to preserve the data for more time)?
Is it pen-drive or DVD or Hard disk?

Or is it any other than these three? I also want to know why one is better than other.
Thank you

Comment: Forget Google, how about searching this very site first?

Answer (score 1):

Tape is the best for real long term storage, they can sit for years and years with no issues what so ever. A Tape is tough, you can drop it or throw it around and it will be fine.

HDD is not a good long term storage medium as by living them to sit without powering them up they can seize up and simply not work. I've also know HDD get wiped clean if stored in an environment that is too cold.

I would say CD/DVD is too fragile i.e one scratch and you've had it for me to trust at all for any long term storage.

A well made pen drive may be a good option as it won't seize up and can be quite robust, however if you buy a cheap one (I know this from experience) the soldering on the board can break/ become damaged.

If I were you I would store on Tape and on USB Drives, and then store one in a fireproof safe and another at a friends house.

Comment: I cannot count the number of bad tapes I have taken out of the archive that don't work.  They were properly stored of course.

Comment: I would suggest that is down to issue with putting the data on the tape rather than issues with the tape, just from my experience anyway.